# Type '{ children: void; header: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting the following error. I am a little new to React, so not sure how to handle it.

`Type '{ children: void; header: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.`

To start with, I have two variables:

```
const recentPitches = this.props.lastPitched.forEach(pitch =>
    <p>
        <small>
            {pitch.pitchingInitiativeName} ({pitch.accountName}) | <span className="text-primary">status</span><br />
            By {pitch.userName} at {moment(pitch.lastPitchTime).format('lll')}
        </small>
    </p>
);
const upcomingPitches = this.props.upcomingPitches.forEach(pitch =>
    <p>
        {pitch.pitchingInitiativeName} ({pitch.accountName}) | {moment(pitch.publishingDeadline).format('lll')}
    </p>
);
```

and then I call them here in my render method which is where the error is being caused:

```
<Collapse>
    <Collapse.Panel header="Most Recent Pitches" key="1">
        {recentPitches}
    </Collapse.Panel>
    <Collapse.Panel header="Upcoming Pitches" key="2">
        {upcomingPitches}
    </Collapse.Panel>
</Collapse>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably meant to use `map`, not `forEach`, on `this.props.lastPitched` and `this.props.upcomingPitches`.  `Array.prototype.forEach` does not return anything, while `Array.prototype.map` gathers the return values of the callback on each element into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

> `Type '{ children: void; header: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'`

TypeScript has inferred that the children (e.g. `recentPitches`) is `void`. Example reason why this can happen:

```
const foo = function(){}
const recentPitches = foo(); // void
```

## Fix

I doubt you want a `void` as the children for `Collapse.Panel`. At the very least that is not what the types for `Collapse.Panel` is expecting and hence the error.

The error is valid. The bug is you have `recentPitches` as `void`. Fix that and the error will go way.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back and I understand what you are saying, but still a little unclear on how to fix it.

Comment: @SandraWillford added another sentence to explain what to fix.

Comment: ok I added an any type to recentPitches and  upcomingPitches and that cleared the error. I am concerned however as to what the correct type is really supposed to be.